# I Want to upload 3 ipa files at time on diawi from Jenkins job and URL for that IPA file should be attached in mail which we sent post build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I Want to upload 3 ipa files at time on diawi from Jenkins job and URL for that IPA file should be attached in mail which we sent post build in editable mail.

Suggestions are welcomes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple files to Diawi using this Jenkins plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/diawi-upload/

Then in *Editable email notification* post-action refer to the download links for each one:

```
${FILE,path="appName1.ipa.diawilink"},
${FILE,path="appName2.ipa.diawilink"},
${FILE,path="appName3.ipa.diawilink"}
```